# Do I Need to create a class for every play form?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Here is the thing: I am new to Play Framework (and ORM), so I tend to follow exactly what the tutorial tells/shows me to do. In Play's tutorial, we first need to create a subclass within the controller, with the same exact variable names as in HTML forms.

For example, I would have this form in HTML:

```
<form action="Controller1/action1">
  <input type="text" name="param1">
  <input type="text" name="param2">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And Controller1 will look like:

```
public class Controller1 extends Controller {

    public static class SubClass1 {
        public String param1;
        public String param2;

        public String validate() {
          if (param1....param2...){
             return "invalid..."
          }
          return null;
        }
    }

    public static Result action0() {
       return ok(somePage.render(form(SubClass1.class)));
    }

    public static Result action1() {
       Form<SubClass1> form = form(SubClass1.class).bindFromRequest();
    }
}
```

Action0 is used to render the page, and initialize it. Action1 is used to receive the form data and process it. I know sometimes you can do this: `form(User.class)` and User is a class in your model.

My Questions are:

1. Should I prefer to use a model class (i.e. `form(User.class)`) to create a form or use a subclass built within the controller like above? 
   (I know essentially my form data goes to model...)
2. Do I need to pass in a form object every time as long as I want to receive it?
3. What is the naming convention of parameters in `SubClass1`? Should the parameter names be exact like names in the HTML form? Can they be different? I don't use form_helper to generate form (I use Foundation 4 not Bootstrap), so I just pass the form to the page and not actually do anything. (Except display errors, or restore values like `value="@form("param1")"`)
4. Someone told me `validate()` built in my SubClass1 will be called by default once I invoke `form.hasErrors()`. Is this true? How can Play know which function should be executed to check data's validity? (Is "validate" a reserved word? How about "authenticate"?)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answers are:

1. No. In my practice using model class as form model is bad idea most times. The problem here is "merging" data after form submit. In real life you never stores all fields of model on form. If you are using your domain class as form model then after submit you will have partially filled domain object that needs to be merged with your domain object from database.
2. Yes
3. As you wish. I just append `Form` or `SomeThingThatDescribesPageForm` to domain class name
4. Sorry, not very familiar with form processing in java.

Comment: @wind-dweller To answer #4... Play uses reflection to check whether your model class has a method called "validate" and, if so, calls it. The `validate()` method will be called only after the regular validation has taken place and no errors were found, so if you annotate a field as `@Required` and it's missing then `validate()` won't be called. Depending on the version of Play there are 3 variants of `validate()` with different return types (String, List, or Map) to handle varying degrees of complexity in your custom validation.